# How to hide views dynamically android?

Tags: android

I receive some user data from server at my app. One of the field which I receive has boolean data type and it changes due to user actions on server. According to value of this variable I have to show/hide a part of my layout. But I don't have enough time for it or I did it in wrong way :( So, first of all I send request at my singleton class and after getting response I save this json field to SharedPreferences:

```
if (!app_data!!.get("questionnaire").isJsonNull) {
    context.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).edit().putBoolean("questionnaire", app_data.get("questionnaire").asBoolean).apply()
}
```

at this time I move to my fragment where I have to change visibility:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
val personalPage = PersonalPage()
if (sp!!.getBoolean("questionnaire", false)) {
  bundle.putBoolean("questionnaire", true)
} else {
  bundle.putBoolean("questionnaire", false)
}

personalPage.arguments = bundle
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentContainerT, personalPage).addToBackStack(null).commit()
bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.home_screen
```

and as you can see I send this variable via bundle but as I see it doesn't work good. And at target fragment I try to change visibility:

```
val bundle = arguments
val cont: RelativeLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.polls_container_view)

if (bundle != null) {
   if (bundle.getBoolean("questionnaire")) {
      if (sp.getBoolean("questionnaire", false) || cont.visibility == View.GONE) {
          fragmentManager!!
             .beginTransaction()
             .detach(PersonalPage())
             .attach(PersonalPage())
             .commit()

      }
   cont.visibility = View.VISIBLE

   val pollsBtn = rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.polls_button)
   val pollsInfo = rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.polls_info)
   pollsBtn.setOnClickListener {
                        activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentContainerT, PollsScr()).addToBackStack(null).commit()
   }


   pollsInfo.setOnClickListener {
      showPollsInfoMSG()
   }


} else {
  if (!sp.getBoolean("questionnaire", false) || cont.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
     fragmentManager!!
       .beginTransaction()
       .detach(PersonalPage())
       .attach(PersonalPage())
       .commit()
   }
  cont.visibility = View.GONE


  }
}
```

But I see that when a user changes variable value from true to false and move to this fragment my view is still visible and I have to reload fragment for hiding view. And also when user receive true from server I also have to reload this fragment. I tried to get bool variable at `onStart()` fun but maybe I don't have enough time for it? Maybe this problem can be solved via broadcast receiver but I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: You can replace fragment PersonalPage in container  rather that attaching and detaching. By the way where you get server data, in PersonalPage or any other place?

Comment: @Mundroid, I send request from my singleton function, and call this function from personalpage fragment

Comment: So if you getting data in personalpage and you want to updated the same fragment then change view visibility once you get data why you want to reload fragment?

Comment: I think that reloading can help me :( I don't know another ways of solving this tasks, I tried all possible solutions

Comment: if (!app_data!!.get("questionnaire").isJsonNull) {
    context.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).edit().putBoolean("questionnaire", app_data.get("questionnaire").asBoolean).apply()
//set visibilty of view here like
if (sp.getBoolean("questionnaire", false)) {
      cont.visibility= VIISBLE
 } else {
       cont.visibility= GONE
 }

}

Comment: you mixed code from singleton and from fragment class?

Comment: app_data!!.get("questionnaire") providing data once you get this data update views